# What memory issues may arise from a single page JavaScript/AJAX application when kept open over a period of months?

Tags: javascript, ajax, memory-management, single-page-application

I am particularly new to the concept of Single-Page Applications (SPA) and I have concerns on what issues may arise from writing such pages meant to be kept open in a browser over a abnormally long period, on the order of a few months.

I understand that there are a few types of SPAs, in particular *stateful* and *stateless* SPAs, and am looking to write one that is stateless. I am not looking to make use of SPA frameworks, and stick to jQuery (or is that a bad option?)

The intention is for it to constantly call an AJAX request every few seconds, and refresh certain parts of the DOM according to the response. In addition, other actions may be done on the user's end, also via AJAX and getting a response on successful/failed execution.

---

My question is, what issues (memory in particular) may arise from keeping a page open that is **actively refreshing** the DOM, over a *really* long period? Will I face a memory leak of some sort, and what do I have to keep in mind while writing my application, (like unbinding unused event listeners)?

I would also like to know if it would be a better option to request the user to refresh the page perhaps every day at a convenient time, to "clear" the memory, or would that be *unnecessary*, because of the browser's in-built garbage collection?

Pardon if this question is off-topic or if there are resources out there which address this issue, as I am new to this.

Comment: impossible to say. that depends ENTIRELY on what your code is doing, and what browser/rendering agent you're using. e.g. if you're using older internet explorers, then good luck getting your app to stay open for more than a few microseconds.

Comment: I have a fixed target user base, and I would say I have the control over what browsers I want them to make use of. Though a particular hurdle may be having to support iPad as well - not sure how that may even work out.

Comment: You'll want to read [Effectively Managing Memory at Gmail scale](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/memory/effectivemanagement/). Other than that, I feel your question is a bit too broad for SO.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the link, I will start from there! I too feel that it is kind of broad as well, but I don't know a better place to ask. SO indeed has the greatest concentration of geniuses and people who are smarter than me.